# Overriding a mutator List to change its type of a child

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

```
public class Schedule_Action : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public List<Action> mondaySchedule = new List<Action>();
        public virtual List<Action> MondaySchedule
        {
            get { return mondaySchedule; }
        }
    }

public class Schedule_ActionHire : Schedule_Action
{
    //causes an error here saying it should match overriden with Action
    public override List<Action_Adventure> MondaySchedule
    {
        get
        {
            return mondaySchedule.Cast<Action_Adventure>().ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

'Action_Adventure' is a child of 'Action'.

Is there a way to bypass the error? Or maybe another way with the same logic as the code give above?

Answer (score 1):

**You can't change the signature of a member you are overriding.**

But using `new` you can hide a member in a base class:

```
public class A
{
    // no 'virtual' here
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class B : A
{
    public new int Value { get; set; }
}
```

However this approach can be very confusing.

Instead you could do the following: derive from `Action` and add an abstract method that will handle things differently:

```
public class Action
{
}

public class ActionAdventure : Action
{
}

public class Base
{
    private readonly List<Action> _actions = new List<Action>();

    public List<Action> Actions
    {
        get { return _actions; }
    }

    // call this from your code
    protected virtual void HandleActions()
    {
        foreach (var action in Actions)
        {
        }
    }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    protected override void HandleActions()
    {
        var adventures = Actions.OfType<ActionAdventure>();
        foreach (var adventure in adventures)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. 'var adventures' is still empty.